# generate custom uri (or url) from named routes with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, parameters, custom-routes

on a Rails3 app, from a Rake task, i want to generate a uri path of a collection page (with a pagination set by the params[:page]), and i wish the outcome had:

- "/mycustomname"
- "/mycustomname/1"
- "/mycustomname/2"
- "/mycustomname/n"

then i have setup the custom rule on routes.rb, according to my needs:

```
get 'mycustomname/:page' => 'mycontroller#myaction', :constraints => { :page => /\d+/ }, :as => "myelement"
get 'mycustomname' => 'mycontroller#myaction', :as => "myelement"
```

then when i try it from console, for example:

```
app.myelement_path(:page=>3)
```

i retrieve the:

- "/mycustomname?page=3"

instead of

- "/mycustomname/3"

What is missing to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the page number literally: `app.myelement_path(3)`

Comment: Wait, I think the second route might be overwriting your first route.

Comment: ok, i have deleted the second rule, and now i retrieve correctly the uri as expectations ... but now if i try without the page param i have an error: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"mycontroller", :action=>"myaction"}

Comment: That constraint means `:page` *must* be present for the url to be built. You might have an easier time if you used the second route only, and just allowed `:page` to be passed in as a parameter on the query string. Then in the controller, if `:page` is blank, do the speical non-page code.

Comment: OK, i have solved with this only rule: get 'mycustomname(/:page)' => 'mycontroller#myaction', :constraints => { :page => /\d+/ }, :as => "myelement"

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working. If you think I helped, please upvote or accept this answer.